# click event on a cell and not entire row - with FIDDLE

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently using this code for `row click` event in a `bootstrap table`

```
$('#myTable').bootstrapTable().on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) 
    {
       //....my operation
    }
```

The problem is this triggers for the entire row and I want to be able to trigger it for a single cell.

> Note I am using the arguments, `row and $element`

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1660/)

Comment: how about checking for the class of the event.target and if it's `myClass`, do `e.stopPropagation();` ?

Comment: as in if any other class other than `myClass` is clicked then do `e.stopPropagation();`....right?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1661/

Comment: @r043v, i would need the `row` and `$element`. Plus the fiddle i shared is what i will be doing. Adding and removing rows on same cell click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$element is the entire row, you cannot know what cell have been clicked by this way,
bootstrap table do not have cell click event, so you need manually add click event on last cell and fill your needed vars yourself

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data
}).on('click','td:last-child',function(){
    var $t = $(this), $row = $t.parent(), i = $row.index(), row = data[i];
    var $firstTd = $row.children().eq(0);
    if($firstTd.data("haveTable") !== true){
        $firstTd.data("haveTable",true);
        $firstTd.append('<table class="newTable"><tr><td>NEW TABLE</td></tr></table>');
    } else {
        $firstTd.data("haveTable",false);
        $firstTd.children("table").remove();
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1663/

Comment: can you please explain your answer in detail. This looks perfect. What is `var $firstTd = $row.children().eq(0);`?? and what is `haveTable`?

Comment: so `row.Id` from the click event mentioned in the Question and the `row.Id` from your answer will be the same?

Comment: row var hold clicked object of your data array used to create the table, nothing more

Comment: and $row will match $element of your fiddle, so the complete clicked row (tr) as a jquery object

Comment: `row = data[i];` will contain the row data, right? For example, name or starts or forks, etc?

Comment: yes :)
you can console.log(row); to see his content

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#myTable').bootstrapTable().on('click-row.bs.table td', function (e, row, $element) 
{
   //....my operation
}
```

Comment: provide the code of the table you are trying to reach....................................

Comment: please check the question, updated the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my guess, when you click on that cell, you probably want only the triggers for that particular cell to execute and not for the whole table.

This can be achieved by stopping the propagation of event from the table cell to the table row.

```
$('#myTable').bootstrapTable().on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element){

    //stop the propagation for target cell
    if($(event.target).hasClass('myClass')) e.stopPropagation();

    //the code for handler
    ...
    ...
}
```

There are many ways `stopPropagation` can be utilized to do this thing. This was just one of those.

Since I dont know how your other triggers are set, I can't write code that works with those with assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#myTable tr td:last-child').on('click', function() {
    if( $('.newTable', $(this)).length ) {
        $('.newTable', $(this)).remove();
    } else {
        $(this).append( '<table class="newTable"><tr><td>NEW TABLE</td></tr></table>' );
    }
});
```

Comment: you can try the changes [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1660/) and the code you gave doesn't work. It only fires for the first cell of the first row only

Comment: I tried your answer and here is the [RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1664/). The problem is it is trying to initialize a new element there and hence show a `No matching records found` message first which shouldn't be there.

Comment: You don't need to do `$('#myTable tr td:last-child').bootstrapTable().on('click-row.bs.table'`, you have already initialized bootstrapTable.  Here's the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rohitrox/e3nk137y/1665/